# Difficulty with Fubini's theorem, proving an equality.

Tags: integration, measure-theory

Suppose we have to measures on a space $X: \mu, \theta$ and define the functions F,G:

$F(x) = \mu(a,x], G(x) = \theta(a,x]$, further $\pi = \mu \times \theta$. and $S=(a,b] \times (a,b]$

I already proved that $\pi(S) = F(b)G(b)$. Now i must prove the following equalities with Fubini's theorem:

$\pi((x,y):a<y \leq x \leq b) = \int_{(a,b]} G(x) d\mu x \space \space (1)$

$\pi((x,y):a<x \leq y \leq b) = \int_{(a,b]} F(y) d\theta y \space \space (2)$

I don't seem to understand how to do this, usually on this type of question i check whether the equality is true for simple functions and just take the limit but that can't be used here.

So far i've seen that the left on for example $(1)$ is the same as:

$F(x)G(y)$, where $x \in (a,b]$ and $y \in (a,x]$. But what magic can one use to see that this is an integral expression and then use Fubini.

Kees

Comment: You might want to clarify that the space $X$ is the interval $[a,b]$ (or so it seems to me...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are typos in your statements. Anyway, here is a way to do the correct version of the second statement: let $A = \{(x,y): a<x≤y≤b\}$. This is Borel measurable. Since its characteristic function is nonnegative measurable, we can apply (Fubini/Tonelli) to conclude that

$$
\int \limits_{(a,b]\times(a,b]} \chi_A \,d\pi = \int \limits_{(a,b]}\int \limits_{(a,b]}\chi_A(x,y) \,d\mu(x) d\theta(y)
$$

You will see from the picture that for $y$ fixed, $\chi_A(x,y)$ is a measurable function of $x$ and equals $\chi_{(a,y]}(x)$.
Thus the inner integral is just $\mu((a,y])$, hence

$$
\int \limits_{(a,b]}\mu((a,y]) \,d\theta(y) = \int \limits_{(a,b]}F(y) \, d\theta(y)
$$

Comment: why is the left term equal to $\pi((x,y):a<x \leq y \leq b)$?

Comment: The measure of a set is the same as the integral of its characteristic function (definition of integral w.r.t a measure)